# How an object created from singleton class that is annotated with term @Service or @Controller is paralellized in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, singleton

Well, the thing is that **Spring** creates only a single object in app context for classes annotated as for instance **@Service** annotation. But, there could be **many HTTP calls in parallel**. So, I wonder if this objects will be also automatically parallelized or won't it become a bottleneck of the application?

Comment: In Spring Eco-system every request is executed in separate thread. A worth reading https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-singleton-bean-serve-multiple-requests-at

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Thank you for the link. It stated exactly those questions I was interested in. Well, it happens that answer is: "... _ideal singleton bean must be stateless_ ". So I guess when we are creating our classes we have to take care of it being stateless. Then it will not become a bottleneck.